# How to return a complete column including duplicate values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created one table with three columns
Table name = chat

Column 1 as ID
column 2 as NUMBERS
column 3 as messages

Column 1 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Column 2 = 1 5 6 4 5 3 5 5 5

Column 3 = R A H S A G A A A

How to write QUERY to retrieve a single COLUMN in the following format

Where column 2 = 5
Then it should return as

Column 3 = A A A A A

I tried group by but it returns me only single A inserted of A A A A A
PLEASE HELP... 
thanks in advance

Comment: When asking your next question, provide sample data in columns instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Column3 from chat where column2 = 5
```

Comment: Not working, the resulting column 3 shows like 
Where column 2 = 1 
It should return R
instead it shows R R R R R

Comment: No, it would only return one R.  You must have done it wrong. `Select Column3 from chat where column2 = 1`

Comment: No, I checked well but it shows  R R R R R only actually I am retrieving the column 3 values in my listview in that listview it shows like that

Comment: Do not assume something by seeing ListView. Check your response from database and print that in logcat.

Comment: Then your listview is probably coded wrong, and IT is repeating the values.